# Parallelization and Testing With Assigned Seed

Tags: python, numpy, conda, jupyter, numba

I'm currently trying to make a test function using pytest inside jupyter lab that compares an expected number to an output number of a function. If the numbers are the same, the test passes, else, fails.

The problem I'm running into is trying to use numba's parallelization while trying to test for expected numbers on an assigned seed. I do not know how to get an expected number out of a function that uses random numbers while parallelization is on.

Here is the test code that I've come up with to replicate the problem

```
np.random.seed(0)

@njit(parallel=True)
def sum_shape(repeats,samples):
    
    sum = 0
    
    for i in prange(0,repeats):
        x = np.random.uniform(0,100,int(samples))
        sum += np.sum(x)
        
    return sum

%%ipytest
def test():
    assert sum_shape(10000,10) == 4995000.330114928 # expected output given seed
```

output:

```
                                                                                            [100%]
============================================ FAILURES =============================================
______________________________________________ test _______________________________________________
```

....

```
    def test():
       assert sum_shape(10000,10) == 4995000.330114928
E       assert 4996808.331482845 == 4995000.330114928
E        +  where 4996808.331482845 = sum_shape(10000, 10)
```

Error:

> C:----\Temp\ipykernel_25272\3934080751.py:2: AssertionError
> ===================================== short test summary info ===================================== FAILED t_01f2dbfbba344083844e69272c66385b.py::test - assert 4996808.331482845
> == 4995000.330114928 1 failed in 1.21s

output without parallelization:

.                                                                                            [100%]
1 passed in 0.05s

Thanks

Comment: This is expected: each thread use its own local seed. AFAIR this is mentioned in the documentation. This is mandatory for multithreading to be useful. In sequential, the default RNG use an iterative random number generator which cannot be parallelized (because it is iterative, each step is dependent of the previous one). Most RNGs uses iterative algorithms.

Comment: Because of that, the result is dependent of the platform : more specifically, the number of threads used. You can fix this issue by splitting data in chunks and having a seed per chunk. This solution is independent of the number of threads though the size of the chunk can limit the scalability of the code (and very small chunks will decrease performance).

Comment: Not an answer per se, but consider this: you are trying to test two (arguably) separate features of your function: 1. Can it produce the exact output I expect with a set seed, and  2. Does it stand up to parallelization? Write a test for each of those things. Execute the test you already have without parallelization to test point 1. Write a separate test for point 2. Use parallelization, but don't use a set seed (you won't use one in practice anyway). Rather, do a qualitative or statistical analysis of the results to decide if the results are satisfactory.

Comment: That second test will be much more representative of the real use of the function and may catch different types of issues.

Comment: You could try to generate the random arrays outside your function and then do the sum with your parallel numba function.